# How to Get gencache.EnsureDispatch Name

Tags: python, win32com

How do you get the name of a `win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispath` name?

For example, I have an application named "xxxxx", and the Python object browser detects it when I use makepy.py.  How do I get name like "Excel.Application"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the combrowser.py to find the running application on your PC. Go to the win32com library folder and you can find the python script.

You can get the list of all the running application. Sometimes it would be tricky if you get the token or moniker of the application instead of the name. But you can use those moniker to reach the application instead.